# Does the root domain hold more power then an inner page?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, url, permalinks

I am building a new site and I am just thinking out the structure of the whole site.

It's is going to be a pretty big site with a lot of different content and I was wondering if the root domain is best to use for blogs that are really important for me to rank.

For instance; say I have a category `electronics`, followed by a subcategory `audio`, followed by a sub-subcategory `headsets`, all my relevant headset blogs would go into `domain.com/electronics/audio/headsets`.

But the most important blog of them all will be something like `best headset`. Would I have a 'better chance' of ranking with:

`domain.com/electronics/audio/headsets/best-headsets`

Or:

`domain.com/best-headsets`

Or doesn't it matter at all?

Could not find a clear answer on Google.